# Flash AS3 raw content of the fault on HTTPService response not available

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex3

I have an HTTPService defined as following

```
<mx:HTTPService id="jsonServ" resultFormat="text" method="GET" useProxy="false"/>
```

I make an invokation of the following type using Flash project:

*https://DOMAIN/json/Invoke?json={"CLASS":"FUNCTION", PARAMETERS}}*

Result work fine but fault come with no raw content and no status code. Air is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: _thanks I will change the code sent from the server to 400 and see. I will comment if it works._

Comment: _no didn't work_ I status code 0 and no content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might correspond to this one [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/joshuafox/entry/handling_http_errors_in_flex?lang=en):

Also check out: http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/

Comment: _thanks that was very useful, I will try that httpclientlib as a work around._